# 8 queens "goto" command bugging me

Tags: c

Ok, so I've done a really weird code for the 8 queens problem. Don't ask how I got to this. The code is successful in calculating the positions for the 8 queens when I set a good position for the first queen ( it's calculated well for the mat[k][l] with k being 5 and l being 0 starting position ). After that I tried to come up with a fix for the program so it could be able to calculate all the positions without a good starting position. So the idea was to calculate the number of queens after the whole code, and if it isn't 8, use the goto command for the code to go back to the beginning. Before which I of course increased the first coordinate by one. So the idea is: start with the starting position 0, 0. If the number of the queens set on the field isn't 8 after the code is done, increase k, go back to the beginning, and try with the starting position of mat[1][0]. And so on until it finds a correct starting position. But, when I run the code ( after the "improvement"), it just crashes and does nothing. When I set k to be 5 at the beginning, so it starts at mat[5][0], the result is calculated well. I suppose that the problem is with the goto command, I just don't know how to fix it cause I think that the idea for the code is good. Some technical issue which I can't seem to fix. Here is the code.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i, j, nul = 0, mat[8][8], tmpi, tmpj, a=0, k=0, l=0;
    label3:
    for (i=0; i<8; i++){
        for(j=0; j<8; j++){
            mat[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    mat[k][l] = 1;
    int n=0;
    label1:
    while( n < 64 ){
        if ( n== 0){
            for (i=0; i<8; i++){
                for(j=0; j<8; j++){
                    if ( mat[i][j] == 1 ){
                        tmpi=i;
                        tmpj=j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (i=0; i<8; i++){
                for(j=0; j<8; j++){
                    if ( j == tmpj &&  i != tmpi ){
                        mat[i][j] = 2;
                    }
                    if( i == tmpi && j != tmpj  ){
                        mat[i][j] = 2;
                    }
                    if ( i + j == tmpi + tmpj && (  i != tmpi && j != tmpj)  ){
                        mat[i][j] = 2;
                    }
                    if ( i - j == tmpi - tmpj && (  i != tmpi && j != tmpj)  ){
                        mat[i][j] = 2;
                    }
                }
            }
            n++;
            goto label1;
        }

        for (i=0; i<8; i++){
            for(j=0; j<8; j++){
                if ( mat[i][j] == 0){
                    mat[i][j] = 1;
                    tmpi = i;
                    tmpj = j;
                    goto label2;
                }
            }
        }

        label2:     
        for (i=0; i<8; i++){
            for(j=0; j<8; j++){
                if ( j == tmpj &&  i != tmpi ){
                    mat[i][j] = 2;
                }
                if( i == tmpi && j != tmpj  ){
                    mat[i][j] = 2;
                }
                if ( i + j == tmpi + tmpj && (  i != tmpi && j != tmpj)  ){
                    mat[i][j] = 2;
                }
                if ( i - j == tmpi - tmpj && (  i != tmpi && j != tmpj)  ){
                    mat[i][j] = 2;
                }
            }
        }
        n++;
    }
    for (i=0; i<8; i++){
        for(j=0; j<8; j++){
            if ( mat[i][j] == 1){
                a++;
            }
        }
    }
    if ( a!= 8 ){
        k++;
        goto label3;
    }



    for (i=0; i<8; i++){
        for(j=0; j<8; j++){
            if ( mat[i][j] == 2){
                printf("%3d", nul);
            }else printf("%3d", mat[i][j]);
        }printf("\n");
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

There is a lot of weird stuff going on, I know. First I set all the positions to 0, then put one position to be 1 ( which is a queen ). Then marked all the positions which the other queens can't be placed upon with 2. Then I filled the gaps with other queens and other 2-s. Then just printf-ed the 2-s as zeroes and the 1-s as 1-s of course. And lots of weird other stuff. :) The point is that the code for finding the positions works well, goto is just making my head hurt :)

Comment: Well, that's exactly why `goto` is considered harmful. There may be legitimate reasons to use `goto`, but this isn't one of them. Split your code into functions that solve a little part of the problem.

Comment: Ok, this is just the most basic version of the code. Gonna try to remove as much of the goto-s as possible and of course split it into a few functions. Thanks everyone, didn't know the goto command was even considered "harmful"

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

```
goto label1;
```

is equivalent to:

```
continue;
```

and will continue the loop `while( n < 64 )`

The statement:

```
goto label2;
```

is a correct use of `goto`: it is the only way to break out of a nested loop without introducing boolean variables that clobber the code.

The statement:

```
goto label3;
```

can be replacedby a loop at `label3` until the `if ( a!= 8 )` (removing the if):

```
for (k=0; a!=8; k++) {
```

Following replacing the gotos with structured code, you may better understand what is going on to fix your algorithm (I didn't look into that).

Comment: ' it is the only way to break out of a nested loop without introducing boolean variables that clobber the code' - well, apart from a function return.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I actually found the problem. The number of the queens ( value a ) didn't reset after the if ( a!= 8 ) switch so a would just keep increasing and never hitting 8. So, I just added a=0 in the if ( a != 8 ) switch , so it resets the value a every time the code doesn't get the right combination, THEN it returns to the beginning. Now it does calculate one of the possible combinations. :) Gonna fix it up a little bit so it looks and works nicer though.